# Host Angular 7 App in Wildfly as static content

Tags: angular, wildfly, undertow

I'm trying to serve an Angular 7 application using path location strategy in a Wildfly application server.

I managed to add the app as static resources, using a static file handler. So it's getting delivered correctly when an exact path is requested. E.g. requesting `http://my-wildfly-server/myApp/` sends the `index.html` of my app.

Since I'm using path location strategy the `index.html` file should be sent to the client for sublinks too. E.g. requesting `http://my-wildfly-server/myApp/my/route` should send the `index.html` of my app as well.

This leads me to my actual question: Is it possible to configure Wildfly or the Undertow subsystem with some kind of filter which is equal to nginx's `try_file` rule? In other words: Serve the correct file, if it exists for a specific request e.g. `http://my-wildfly/myApp/styles.css` or otherwise fall back to the `index.html` and let Angular take care of the route?

If possible I'd like to avoid bundling my WebApp into a WAR-file or change it to use hash location strategy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of completeness I post here my other solution to achieve my original goal. :)
As I described in the comments of @Tyrone's answer, I ended up bundling the compiled Angular application into a WAR-File and adding the following files to the `WEB-INF` folder:

`jboss-web.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/schema/jboss-web_5_1.xsd">
    <context-root>/</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

I wanted my web application to be hosted in the root of the web server. Therefore the `context-root` is `/`...

`undertow-handlers.conf`

```
path-prefix('/api') -> done
regex('^(.*\/)(.*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,5})$') -> done
path-prefix('/en') -> rewrite('/en')
path-prefix('/de') -> rewrite('/de')
path-prefix('/') -> rewrite('/en')
```

All my `/api` calls should go directly to the corresponding route (configured in the API WAR-File). The second line with the regex ensures, that every call to something which is most probably a file, goes through directly as well... Since I have a multi-language application I need to redirect the different languages to the index.html file of the correct folder (line 3 and 4). And last but not least, if the root of the web server is hit I want to redirect to the default language, which in my case is English (line 5).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I recently had a similar challenge, of 404 when a refresh was requested. My initial web search led to the need for URL rewriting. The following resolved my issue:
1 - A Filter Ref for rewrite rule

```
<filter-ref 
 name="angular-refresh"
 predicate="not equals(%R, '/') and not equals(%R, '/index.html') and not path-prefix('/assets/')
 and not regex('^\/.*.(js|js.map)$') and not regex('^\/.*.(css)$')
 and not regex('^\/.*.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$') and not regex('^\/.*.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$')
 and regex('^(.*)$')"
/>
```

The filter above captures for me the general resources that are real files and then the routes managed by Angular, the filter is one line, just added line breaks for clarity.

2 - Rewrite rule

```
<rewrite name="angular-refresh" target="/index.html" redirect="false"/>
```

One important point to note in the rewrite rule is `redirect="false"` this keeps the route in the address bar.

I hope this helps you resolve your current challenge.

Comment: Nice solution! Thank you! I ended up bundling my app in a war-file and use a pretty similar filter stored to a undertow-handlers.conf in the WEB-INF folder. I initially wanted to avoid listing all file extensions and just deliver the index.html as a fallback if the originally requested file could not have been found (nginx is capable of doing so), but I didn't find any solution for Undertow...

Comment: @nioe  can you share your your undertow file? I'm having a tough time getting my refresh to work from .war file.